# RxSwift callback return first before result

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, rx-swift

I am using Firebase FirAuth API and before the API return result, Disposables.create() has been returned and it's no longer clickable (I know this might due to no observer.onCompleted after the API was called. Is there a way to wait for it/ listen to the result?

```
public func login(_ email: String, _ password: String) -> Observable<APIResponseResult> {

    let observable = Observable<APIResponseResult>.create { observer -> Disposable in

        let completion : (FIRUser?, Error?) -> Void =  {  (user, error) in

            if let error = error {
                UserSession.default.clearSession()
                observer.onError(APIResponseResult.Failure(error))
                observer.on(.completed)
                return
            }

            UserSession.default.user.value = user!
            observer.onNext(APIResponseResult.Success)
            observer.on(.completed)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: completion)
        }

        return Disposables.create()
    }

    return observable

}
```

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous and is not designed to return data in a synchronous way. While you can Force that pattern, it's going to cause a lot of long term issues. All of the DispatchQueue's and callbacks should be removed or else it will be a nightmare to troubleshoot. Let Firebase do it's job; once data is available inside a Firebase closure, then move on to the next step in your UI, process that data etc. The code may be way overly complex - perhaps if you could explain what you are trying to accomplish, a clear solution could be provided instead of workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. What I want to achieve is to return the correct response to view controller for me to redirect(if success) or to emit alert(if error). In this case I always get an empty error as it always return first for error scenario

Comment: Just change the process: capture the user information, then create the user via the Firebase call. Inside the closure you will either have an error (examine the error code for the cause) and tell the user about the error *or* no error so you can proceed to show the next viewController or whatever the next step is. Should be about 6 lines of code and can be done without dispatch queue's and callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption that an onError / onCompletion event terminate the Observable Sequence. Meaning, the sequence won't emit any more events, in any case.

As a sidenote to that, You don't need to do `.on(.completed)` after `.onError()` , since onError already terminates the sequence.

the part where you write `return Disposables.create()` returns a Disposable object, so that observable can later be added to a DisposeBag that would handle deallocating the observable when the DisposeBag is deallocated, so it *should* return immediately, but it will not terminate your request.

To understand better what's happening, I would suggest adding `.debug()` statements around the part that uses your Observable, which will allow you to understand exactly which events are happening and will help you understand exactly what's wrong :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I want to understand how RxSwift can work with Firebase API hence I'm trying to call and waiting for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue some time ago, I wanted to display an `Alert` in `onError` if there was some error, but without disposing of the observable.

I solved it by catching the error and returning an `enum` with the cases `.success(MyType)` and `.error(Error)`

An example:

```
// ApiResponseResult.swift
enum ApiResponseResult {
    case error(Error) 
    case success(FIRUser)  
}

// ViewModel
func login(...) -> Observable<ApiResponseResult> {
    let observable = Observable.create { ... }
    return observable.catchError { error in
        return Observable<ApiResponseResult>.just(.error(error))
    }
}

// ViewController
viewModel
    .login
    .subscribe(onNext: { result in 
        switch result {
        case .error(let error):
            // Alert or whatever
            break
        case .success(let user):
            // Hurray
            break
        } 
    })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```